# Wireless network not connecting in Kubuntu 11.04

Tags: wireless, kubuntu

I've got a fairly fresh install (a month old) of Kubuntu without much modification done to it and I'm having massive issues connecting to any wireless network.  The computer can see the networks available and on trying to connect to my home network it will get to Setting Network Address before waiting for a while and then cutting the connection.

Sometimes the connection works, most of the time it doesn't.  I've got this script which sometimes helps, but sometimes doesn't:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo dhclient -r wlan0
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

I don't really know too much about how to troubleshoot this issue (I'm a bit of a *ubuntu noob) - can anyone help?

---

here's my wifi card info :

> ```
>    description: Wireless interface
>    product: Centrino Advanced-N 6205
>    vendor: Intel Corporation
>    physical id: 0
>    bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
>    logical name: wlan0
>    version: 34
>    serial: a0:88:b4:58:d1:c4
>    width: 64 bits
>    clock: 33MHz
>    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
>    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=2.6.38-10-generic firmware=17.168.5.2 build 35905 ip=192.168.2.53 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
>    resources: irq:48 memory:f2500000-f2501fff
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not related to network manager but wireless drivers:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1752851

Solution is in the last post in the link, although it's not easy.

Just to avoid link rot: solution is to install from source `compat-wireless` using laptop's wifi firmware.

Comment: the instuctions were that difficult actually - helps that I'm running an X220 too!  Thank you very much

Comment: Actually this didn't work :(  Initially it did, but still having problems connecting to wireless networks.

Comment: If you changed kernel (updated your system) you have to recompile `compat-wireless` again.

Comment: Yup - that worked - bonus points for you.

Answer (score 2):

I found another workaround. For me switching the hardware-wireless-switch off and on again "solves" the problem.

It's working on a x220i, Ubuntu 11.10 64bit...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an alternate network manager such as Wicd?

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

Not promising it will work though. I was on the same boat as you a year or two back and it was soooo frustrating. D:

What wireless card do you have? Use this command to find out.

```
 gksudo lshw -C network
```

Comment: I don't have gksudo.  Have done a bit of research but didn't find any good reasons to install it, do I need it?  Also I haven't tried wicd, but a little worried about possible side effects if I install it.  How easy is it to revert?

Comment: Kubuntu uses: kdesudo